# How to make SQL Server order fields by 'Id' (which in this case is an Identity column)

Tags: sql-server, windows, c#

I have an SQL Server table that i post into using C#. I would like the fields to be ordered using Id. Instead i get something like this:

[image]

I need the id column to be arranged in order of increasing number because i use a data table in C# to go through these values one at a time, therefore jumping from 7 to 9 to 11 back to 8 is very inconvenient.

N.B: I'm not talking about select * from table_name order by id. I need the values to be 'permanently stored' in the order requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now, when you say:

> I need the id column to be **arranged in order** of increasing number **because I use a data table** in C# to go through these values one at a time, therefore jumping from 7 to 9 to 11 back to 8 is very inconvenient.

it shows some confusion. There are two issues here that are orthogonal to each other:

- the internal order that rows are stored
- the order that the rows are returned in a result set

These two are not to be confused. The internal order is a matter of the database's physical design while the order of a result set can vary from query to query, depending on the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Tables are inherently unordered.** Despite that, in many DBMS - and in this case SQL Server - we have the option to add a "clustering index" on a table, so there is a B-tree index (with the chosen order) that leads to the rows.

This is however irrelevant to the order that a result set is presented. The only way to have a guaranteed order in the result set is to specify an `ORDER BY` clause.

If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the order can be arbiratry:

- you may have a heap (table without clustered index) and still sometimes see the result ordered by `id` and sometimes in a random order.
- you may have a clustered table and still sometimes see the result ordered by `id` and sometimes in a random order.

Notice that there is no difference above. The underlying table structure doesn't guarantee an order.

---

So, if you do want the rows stored in a specific order on disk, make `(id)` the clustered index. But note that without an `ORDER BY id`, you will still get the results in arbitrary order.

Comment: You're right. I have specified the `Select * from table_name ORDER By Id` statement on my C# end so that datatable is populated in this order. I have resorted to using this method after considering that the user has no care of how data in the database is arranged.
 
 By doing so i guarantee my preferred order in my 'datatable' instead of the database:
 
 I will leave the database arranged in its current state.